# Regex - match from N-th occurence of a character till end of string

Tags: javascript, regex, sublimetext2

Going slightly mad here :) because this must be simple and I just can't crack it.

**Example:**

```
HTZ_2015_CS_SS5_cncenter_1020x200_AS2_10K.html
HTZ_2015_CS_SS5_cncenter_1020x200_AS2_10K.swf
HTZ_2015_CS_SS5_cncenter_1500x1000_160K_w1020.jpg
```

- match 6th "_" (underscore character), select it and everything that follows, till the end of the string
- replace with nothing (basically delete from 6th underscore to the end of string)

I am using Sublime Text for all my text editing, with *Find/Replace* function but if necessary I could use some online tool (any suggestions?). These as you might have guessed it are banner file names which we regularly need to modify, hundreds of them at a time.

Many thanks!

P.S. I can write simple JS so maybe this is also an option if must be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are **sure** that there are at least 6 _ in the string :

```
   src.match (/^((?:[^_]*_){5}[^_]*)(_[^]*)$/)[1]
```

'HTZ_2015_CS_SS5_cncenter_1020x200_AS2_10K.html'.match (/^((?:[^*]**){5}[^*]*)(*[^]*)$/)[1] == 'HTZ_2015_CS_SS5_cncenter_1020x200'

Otherwise use :

```
  (src.match (/^((?:[^_]*_){5}[^_]*)(_[^]*)$/) || [,src])[1]
```

Comment: Tx for the answer! What is this part "(src.match" ... and then "|| [, src][1]"? I am using Regex101 tester and replacing there. When done I copy values from "SUBSTITUTION" panel into my txt file.

Comment: `src.match` returns an array if the match succeeds or null if there is no match, the `|| [,src]` will be invoked in the event of no match and return an array with element 1 being the original string. So the whole JavaScript expression effectively will do you replacement or nothing if there is no match. Regex101 will not allow you to test this. I will put up a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
^((?:[^_]*_){5}[^_]*).*$
```

You can try this.Replace by `$1` or `\1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/36

Comment: Ahaa, sorry I tried it in Sublime and there it didn't work. @regex101 it works. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexStarbuck are you using `m` `multiline` flag

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a Perl-like regex for Sublime text:

```
\b(?:[^_]*_){5}[^_]*\K(.*)\b
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bD9yE3/7).

It captures:

```
_AS2_10K.html
_AS2_10K.swf
_160K_w1020.jpg
```

Comment: Hey, thx for the reply BUT - I need to select 6th underscore and everything that follows. This one selects everything after the 7th (last) underscore and leaves the underscore out.

Comment: This one is better :) but still doesn't capture the 6th underscore. The selection begins AFTER the underscore. (and it doesn't work in SUblime)